# How to keep alias setting with doskey in Azure pipeline？

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, doskey

I am using Azure pipeline with [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops) to run a local script **init.cmd**, which is mainly for alias setting with [doskey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/doskey). I am using the following YAML file to configure the pipeline

```
trigger:
- master

pool: $(AGENT_POOL)

steps:
- script: |
    init.cmd
    build
  displayName: 'init.cmd'
  workingDirectory: $(CODE_BASE)
```

the alias setting seems not to work:

```
'build' is not recognized as an internal or external command
```

Comment: You are using build command. Does it exist in workingDirectory: $(CODE_BASE)?

Comment: @AndriyBilous `build` is an alias, which will be in effect after run `init.cmd`.  it will go well after run `build` if we use the manual command rather than putting them in the Azure pipeline.

Comment: Could you please share code from init.cmd?

Comment: What is your build command? Do you mean you need to use this commend under the Doskey.exe? Could you please share us the screenshots about the manual command on your local machine?